# Rails Windows Vagrant very slow response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, performance, vagrant

I'm running:

```
 - Vagrant 1.7.1
 - Rails 4.1.4
 - Thin 1.6.1
 - Windows 7
```

Every static file takes more than a second to be sent. A page can take around 20 seconds to load on my PC, while on the colleague's Linux machine it takes an instant. There were [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574824/rails-vagrant-windows-changes-in-controller-delayed) that say webrick's reverse DNS lookup was the problem, but nobody is saying that Thin suffers from the same problem.

Vagrant file:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "custom_box"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
end
```

Comment: paste your `Vagrantfile` here first

Comment: The latest version of Vagrant is 1.7.1 ... I have no idea if this will fix your problem, but IMHO it's worth to try and upgrade and see if it does. Even if it doesn't, it will make reporting issues etc. easier (this will probably be the first question asked when you report an issue) ... You should also consider upgrading rails to at least 4.0.12, and maybe even 4.1.8 if possible (4.0 -> 4.1 should be easy) ... This applies to other gems (such as thin, sprockets, etc.) as well...

Comment: updated rails and vagrant, problem remains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying a few things, nothing worked. I couldn't make nfs work on windows.
Then I found about rsync! It solved the performance issue perfectly.
See more about rsync and vagrant here:
http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html

On windows, use it with mingw, it works right away:
http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: Much, much better. Definitely a speed improvement.

Comment: I had a lot of issues getting rsync to work, but once I did, this solved my server speed problem. For anyone about to install rsync, install it using cygwin and also install cygwin's ssh client. I installed using mingw first, and kept getting a error on vagrant up during the initial rsync.

Answer (score 1):

[Synced folder](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/index.html) performance on Windows is abysmal with Virtualbox (which is the default). I'd suggest installing [WinNFSd plugin](https://github.com/GM-Alex/vagrant-winnfsd) for Vagrant and then adding these two lines to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
```

That will add NFS support on Windows which has some kinks but still 10x better than the default.

Comment: I couldn't get it to run rails properly. It was super weird. When I tried "rails s" it gave me error  "Not a directory - /vagrant/tmp/pids/server.pid (Errno::ENOTDIR)". I created a file server.pid, then tried to start again and it gave me "already running". I deleted the server.pid file and finally managed to run the server. When I did make a request it appeared on the console, but the request never finished. I'm not doing some config properly, but I have no clue which one.

Comment: @Kazmin Acutally I always run into that error first time I boot up the machine. Here's how I get around it - Once you are in your rails application dir, navigate to tmp/pids, then type 'touch test' and then 'rm test'. Basically creating and deleting some garbage file. After that go back to your app root and run 'rails s'. That should work normally now. Also try running vagrant in powershell with administrator privileges. If you get it working, the speed improvement is worth all it's quirks.

Comment: the removing trick worked, however even though I started vagrant with a powershell, when I made a request to the server I didn't get a reply. I see the get request on the console, but after that no code is executed.

Comment: @Kazmin Strange. Try one of these suggestions to see if you can see a trace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542714/how-to-enable-trace-for-a-ruby-on-rails-application

Comment: Using a debugger doesn't change anything. I get "Started GET "/" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-01-29 02:03:32 +0200" on the console and then it hangs.

Comment: @Kazmin I actually encounter this issue once in a while and I have to find and kill the rails process : 'ps aux | grep rails' & 'sudo kill -9 [pid]' and then start the server again after which it works fine.

Comment: Regrettably, it didn't help. I killed it a few times started it again, but no result.

Comment: @Kazmin Bummer. I've also given up on WinNFSd for now (too many quirks) and switched over to using vagrant-unison plugin instead. It's not as fast but it's very reliable and faster than the default Virtualbox synced folder.

Comment: I'll definitely give that a try, have you ever tried Vagrant with VMWare?

Comment: @Kazmin Nope I have not, I hear it's not as feature full as Virtualbox.

Comment: I think I'll give it a try when I have a bit more time and I'll let you know of the result. I don't think it will be an inferior option, it's paid, it should be quirk free :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign hostname and private IP to it.

```
$ cat Vagrantfile

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "custom_box"
     config.vm.host_name = "rails.example.com"
     config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.1.1"
     config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
  end   
end
```

After updated the `Vagrantfile`, start it with:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Then access the website `http://192.168.1.1:3000` from your own computer, should be faster now.

Comment: I added: 
  config.vm.host_name = "rails.example.com"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
And when I accessed the site through 192.168.33.10:3000 the static files still took around 20 seconds to load

Comment: No difference here.

Answer (score 0):

File system is the problem. I've managed to "install" nfs on windows 10 with Winnfsd, by following those instructions:

https://github.com/dziad/WinNFSdBinary/wiki

After installation WinNFSd refused to run - msvcr120d.dll library was missing so I followed this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8WuKaHslvA

And it finally runs! Much faster than before, but again, not as fast I expected (running it on samsung evo ssd), but it's usable.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm running windows 10 and decided to try Linux Subsystem on Windows. It works great, this is by far the best solution for developing Rails apps on Windows.